# Does built-in functions add in a call stack?

Tags: javascript

I am new in js and reading eloquent javascript book but the call stack part is confusing me. This is the sample code:

```
debugger;
function greet(who) { 
debugger;
  console.log("Hello " + who);
}
debugger;
greet("Harry");
debugger;
console.log("hi");  
console.log("bye");
```

This is what I have observed, debugger and console.log is an anonymous call. function greet gets defined in the global scope, but when I hit the line 7, there's still an anonymous call on the stack and function greet gets added on the stack? but why is there anonymous? can someone please tell me more about the call stack and what is happening here?

Comment: `debugger` is not an anonymous call, or any type of call at all. It is an instruction, just like `i++` is an instruction.

Comment: I thought it was because when I hit the code line on debugger, there is anonymous call on the stack? @MultiplyByZer0

Comment: console.log is a variable with an anonymous function inside. Imagine `console.log = function() {}`

Comment: I don't understand your question. "I hit the line on debugger" - can you clarify this?

Comment: @HollyPony As the console.log function has a name (`console.log.name == "log"`), it would not be anonymous

Comment: @MultiplyByZer0 i thought debugger was adding the anonymous call on the call stack. when I run this on my console. for example, When the code pauses on line 1 where there is the debugger; I got anonymous call on the stack. if it is not. where does this anonymous call come from what function?

Comment: may be the function inside which you wrote these lines is anonymous

Comment: The top-level code of your `<script>` block has no name, so it's an anonymous function created internally by the browser.

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All code that is top-level (not in a function) is automatically moved into an internal function by the JS engine. Your code would be converted to:

```
(function() {
    debugger;
    function greet(who) { 
        debugger;
        console.log("Hello " + who);
    }
    debugger;
    greet("Harry");
    debugger;
    console.log("hi");  
    console.log("bye");
})();
```

This is the anonymous function that is at the bottom of the call stack.